# Secure $_GET & mysql usage?

Tags: php, mysql

So I am trying to make some sort of page with stories for example

```
if(!empty($_GET['page']) && ctype_digit($_GET['page'])) {
    $id = mysql_escape_string($_GET['page']); //in case ctype_digit didnt work well.
    $pDatabase = Database::getInstance();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM stories WHERE id = '$id'";
    $result = $pDatabase->query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) >0){
        //displaying current story
    }
    else {
        header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    }
}
else {
    //Show all short stories
}
```

I want to make sure it is completely safe using $_GET method and mysql query this way , if its not please tell what will be better in this case. Also another thing that bothers me is that I use the query all the time , is it right or should I have some function that would preread all database info before even site launched ? I Mean , what if I want to store Tags or site Title in the Database? Will it be wrong executing (mysql query) title and tags of every page within every page load?

Answer (score 2):

**You should not be using MySQL functions built in to PHP, because they are deprecated. Use *MySQLi* or *PDO*** and learn about prepared statements. I will start by guiding you in the right direction. Trust me, it is worth your time to worry about this, because not using prepared statements could increase chances of SQL injection.

**MySQLi** - http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqli.php

**More about prepared statements with MySQLi** - http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

**PDO** - http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php

**More about prepared statements with PDO** - http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: What would be better , MySQLi or PDO ?

Comment: Whatever you need, if you need different databases like oracle, use PDO. But if you're only using MySQL, use MySQLi. Look at this. But NOTE this is what you need, so just look at what you need or your team. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059

Comment: Gonna go for PDO I guess, I use only MySQL , but who knows what will I need in Future :). Thanks